# past perfect VS simple past + until

Tags: past-perfect

"He says there’s more to learn about Columbia’s history with slavery, which wasn’t abolished in New York until 1827."

This is from AP news script.

I'm confused with the use of the use of past perfect.

Shouldn't it be "which had not been abolished in New York until 1827."?

Can you use simple past with 'until'?

Comment: More context would be preferable, but it is quite possible that 'He says' is a past historic usage, which really messes up sequencing of tenses. In any case, present perfect is often used where past perfect might be expected.

Comment: Yes, you can use simple past with "until": "We were there until 8:00."  "I laughed until my sides hurt."  "She squeezed the packet until ketchup exploded across the floor."  etc. etc.